# I'm trying to upload an array of images using Alamofire but getting error

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipartform-data, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload an array of images to the server using Alamofire 4.8.2

Here is the function:

```
func uploadMultiplePhotos(centreId: Int, imagesArray: [UIImage]) {

    let parameters = ["ec_id": centreId, "uploaded_image": imagesArray] as [String : Any]
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData : MultipartFormData) in

        let count = imagesArray.count

        for i in 0..<count{

            multipartFormData.append(imagesArray[i], withName: "photo[\(i)]", fileName: "photo\(i).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")


        }
        for (key, value) in parameters {

            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
        print(multipartFormData)
    }, to: storeCentreImageURL) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _ , _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

                print("uploding: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in

                print(response.result.value!)

            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("failed")
            print(encodingError)

        }
    }

}
```

getting error in the line below:

```
multipartFormData.append(imagesArray[i], withName: "photo[\(i)]", fileName: "photo\(i).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(UIImage, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the image to data

```
imagesArray.indices.forEach {
  multipartFormData.append(imagesArray[$0].jpegData(compressionQuality:0.8)!, withName: "photo[\($0)]", fileName: "photo\($0).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but getting error as "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStorageCSo7UIImage_$ dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000175c0c0'
*** First throw call stack:" while trying to upload.

Comment: Can you Please check if I'm sending the parameters in the correct way. I've to send the id and array of images.